# jwplayer not playing video on some phones, error code 4

Tags: javascript, android, jwplayer

I am getting on one of android phones error from jwplayer:

Error playing media:

MediaError {
  code 4
}

Tried to search what does it mean, but cannot find.

Video works on other android devices, and on desktop computers. Tried chrome and default browser in android.

**Update**

http://jsfiddle.net/HCH8Q/3/

```
 jwplayer('myElement').setup({ 
        file: 'http://video.oitlabs.com/dogs6_2mb/mr6d_1047.mp4', 

        // works
        // file: 'http://videos-jp.jwpsrv.com/zWLy8Jer/videos/i8oQD9zd-1753142.mp4?77c801d752d5207784c49e7ed80fb953798fae0fcca03ecf79558597ab74bd0b969af6ee1babdc6fac893174bba3c1bbb98ef7c2e4c6b3c59a812b4ed2c9abb29c61117869dbacbbb7caced845a8994ff297cc03a4',
        height: 360, 
        image: '/uploads/example.jpg',
        width: 640 
      });
```

So video from their site works, but my video does not. But when I run that video not in jw player but directly in the address bar its url, it plays. So it means browser is able to play that video.

This happens btw on LG L7 P710 phone

**Update:**

Tried now to upload to my server the video from jw site, and it works on that phone.
http://jsfiddle.net/HCH8Q/5/
So this is encoding issue.  Then the question comes - how should I solve it? I used Handbrake program to convert videos, it has many of settings but I am not sure what should I set to convert so it would work on every phone which supports mp4 files?

**Update:**
Finally made it work by this site instructions:
http://www.broken-links.com/2010/07/30/encoding-video-for-android/

> The first is cross-platform, using Handbrake. What I did with this was to use the iPhone & iPod Touch preset, check the Web Optimized option, and change the Average bitrate option (in the Quality section) to ~1000kbps (you should then save this as a new preset called Android).
>   You’ll also need to change the size of the output video in the Picture Settings options — I changed mine to 480 wide (keeping the aspect ratio) and they came out really crisp and sharp. You can see the result of that below (if your browser supports it).

It looks like everything I done same earlier, **except that I used much smaller kbps setting and picture size left default.** Will later try to experiment which caused to make it work, because still it does not make sense for me how different bitrate or picture size can make it not work. It should be just affecting quality.

**Update**
Had another problem - when using handbrake and trying to convert many files at once, first file picture width gets converted to what I set, but other files - to the default, maybe some bug or something. 
But then I tried another program - Freemake Video converter - it has various params and I tried convert 2 files at once, and were no problems, worked on that phone also. 
http://www.freemake.com/free_video_converter/

Comment: Probably an encoding error, but without a link to your site, we'd just be taking wild guesses.

Comment: In Handbrake, don't mess with the settings. Launch it, accept all of the defaults, but check "Web optimized." The resulting file will almost always be encoded correctly for all platforms. Do NOT overthink this.

Comment: The thing is I needed to compress videos also, so I had to go with bitrate settings at least. And also I read that I should not have checked Large File Size which is checked by default.

Comment: Could you check this question again - why I get downvoted? I created a question here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237457/what-is-wrong-with-this-specific-question and tried to edit this based on comments, but not understanding what else should I edit or maybe this is edited well and just no one saw who could upvote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MediaError { code 4 } is not a JW Player error.

I would recommend taking the video from our site, uploading it to your hosting, and then seeing if it still works. That way you can determine if the issue is encoding based, or a server side issue.

Comment: somehow I doubt that it is server side issue, because if it was, then it would not work on other phones and desktop, would it?

Comment: I was simply suggesting taking the steps to determine if the issue is encoding based or server based. Did you even try my suggestion?

Comment: I did updates in the question which show how did I solve the problem. If you have downvoted, could you recheck the question? Or otherwise tell - what is exactly wrong?